# Reasoning behind 0 validation accuracy in the following ResNet50 model for classification

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have written this [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FJxDmuUlRSC0OWWUlcW50QXeb3d0NS09) to classify Cats and dogs using Resnet50. Actually while studying I came to the conclusion that Transfer learning gives very good accuracy for deep learning models, but I ended getting a far worse result and I didn't understand the cause for it. Any description with reasoning would be very helpful. The dataset contains 2000 images of cats and dogs as training and 1000 images as the validation set.

The following summarises my model

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D
num_classes = 2
IMG_SIZE = 224
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
my_new_model=tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, pooling='avg', classes=2)
my_new_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
 preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
 rotation_range=40,
 width_shift_range=0.2,
 height_shift_range=0.2,
 shear_range=0.2,
 zoom_range=0.2,
 horizontal_flip=True,)

# Note that the validation data should not be augmented!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     train_dir,  # This is the source directory for training images
     target_size=(224,224),  # All images will be resized to 224x224
     batch_size=20,
     class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     validation_dir,
     target_size=(224, 224),
     class_mode='binary')

my_new_model.fit_generator(
     train_generator,
     epochs = 8,
     steps_per_epoch=100,
     validation_data=validation_generator)
```

For this I get the training logs as,

```
Train for 100 steps, validate for 32 steps
Epoch 1/8
100/100 - 49s - loss: 7889.4051 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7834.5318 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7809.7583 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7775.1556 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7808.4858 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7765.3964 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7808.0520 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7764.0735 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.7891 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7762.4891 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.6872 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7762.1766 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.6633 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7761.9766 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.6514 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7761.9346 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f5adff722b0>
```

Comment: Can you show the training logs? You can set verbose=1 in model.fit and share it by pasting as a github gist.

Comment: Try class_mode=categorical instead of binary as you have 2 neurons and so you will need one hot encoded output. [Documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory)

Comment: @SajanGohil I tried that before, but it is giving, Incompatible shapes: [20,2] vs. [20,2048] error.

Comment: What is your folder heirarchy? Are there 2 folders inside your train and validation directory, related to the classes?

Comment: @SajanGohil Yes there are two folders inside my train directory and validation directory.

Comment: Just realized you have include_top=False. If you are using imagenet weights, without top, you will have to add the final dense layers yourself, if you want the classes included, you will have to set include_top to true and weights to None

Comment: @SajanGohil When I add the dense layers like [this](https://pastebin.com/u5vWa1VJ),  It's giving error like this, "Shapes (1, 1, 256, 512) and (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible"

Comment: I think the resnet is in functional api (if it is a "Model" object then functional, "model" for sequential) To use it sequentially, you have to convert it, otherwise there maybe issues with further processing. Also, you will have to check where the model ends, if it ends at dropout, you will have to add a global average pooling and then all the dense layers, you can check it with model.summary()

Answer (score 0):

When i replicated your model with the addition of flatten layer between resnet (i.e Base_net) and dense layer as below

```
Base_net = ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = input_shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Base_net)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = num_classes, activation = 'softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer = 'Adam',
            metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Output:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Model)             (None, 7, 7, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 100352)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 100353    
=================================================================
Total params: 23,688,065
Trainable params: 23,634,945
Non-trainable params: 53,120
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/3
100/100 [==============================] - 84s 837ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5085 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/3
100/100 [==============================] - 81s 806ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.4953 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5050
Epoch 3/3
100/100 [==============================] - 80s 801ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.4965 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5080
```

To fix your problem, you have to change loss function to `binary_crossentropy` and replace activation function with `sigmoid` in last dense layer thus resolved your issue. For better accuracy values please implement hyper parameter tuning.

Note: *We usually observe that the batch size to be the power of 2, this is because of the effective work of optimized matrix operation libraries*

Please refer work code in below where accuracy

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

train_dir  = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/train'
test_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/test'

img_width, img_height = 224, 224
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

#train_samples = 2000
#test_samples = 1000
epochs = 8
batch_size = 32

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255)

train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')

test_data = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    #batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')



# The Convolutional Base of the Pre-Trained Model will be added as a Layer in this Model

Conv_Base = ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = input_shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv_Base)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer = 'Adam',
            metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(
        train_data,
        steps_per_epoch = 100,
        epochs = 8,
        validation_data = test_data,
        verbose = 1,
        validation_steps = 32)
```

Output:

```
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.

Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Model)             (None, 7, 7, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 100352)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 256)               25690368  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 49,278,337
Trainable params: 49,225,217
Non-trainable params: 53,120
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/8
100/100 [==============================] - 1828s 18s/step - loss: 1.9865 - accuracy: 0.6401 - val_loss: 0.7398 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/8
100/100 [==============================] - 65s 646ms/step - loss: 0.6642 - accuracy: 0.6951 - val_loss: 0.7094 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/8
100/100 [==============================] - 65s 652ms/step - loss: 0.5662 - accuracy: 0.7673 - val_loss: 0.7088 - val_accuracy: 0.4950
Epoch 4/8
100/100 [==============================] - 65s 647ms/step - loss: 0.4362 - accuracy: 0.8330 - val_loss: 0.7026 - val_accuracy: 0.4950
Epoch 5/8
100/100 [==============================] - 65s 649ms/step - loss: 0.3998 - accuracy: 0.8405 - val_loss: 0.8281 - val_accuracy: 0.5070
Epoch 6/8
100/100 [==============================] - 65s 647ms/step - loss: 0.5733 - accuracy: 0.7986 - val_loss: 0.8699 - val_accuracy: 0.4970
Epoch 7/8
100/100 [==============================] - 65s 647ms/step - loss: 0.6359 - accuracy: 0.7860 - val_loss: 0.7071 - val_accuracy: 0.5020
Epoch 8/8
100/100 [==============================] - 65s 653ms/step - loss: 0.5514 - accuracy: 0.7673 - val_loss: 0.6590 - val_accuracy: 0.5910
```